# How to disable or enable windows shield with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

So I'm making an HWID Spoofer! I want to give users an option to disable or enable the antivirus. What command can I use to do it?

I have tried:

```
os.system('sc stop WinDefend')
```

and also the sub process version, but both in vain...

Using Python 3 [Specifically 3.8]

Comment: what's the error you're encountering?

Comment: If I try the os.system version, I get the permission denied error
If i try the powershell subprocess version, i get the unexpected token error
The powershell command i used is: Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false

Comment: it's my understanding that sc requires admin privileges to run, which probably explains your permission denied error.  as for powershell... not familiar with it; but I'd expect the same situation to be the same.

Comment: @ewong I have set the app to open only when it is given administrator, so automatically that should fix the issue...